# coremediaio plugin hardware snapshot, brightness control, etc. properties?

Tags: macos, plugins, iokit, core-media

I'm expanding my CoreMediaIO DAL plugin based on the [sample codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CoreMediaIO/Introduction/Intro.html) provided by Apple. I would like to add the support for color control properties such as brightness, hue, contrast, etc through the standard protocols...

As far as I've gone through the entire sample project, there is not much about where and how to correctly expose these control properties. has anyone successfully exposed properties such as

```
    kCMIOFeatureControlClassID
    kCMIOBrightnessControlClassID
    kCMIOSharpnessControlClassID
```

I tried to create an array list similar to the one in sample code but no success. It looks like this:

```
    CACFArray controlList(true);
    CACFDictionary ControlListItem1(true);

    ControlListItem1.AddSInt32(CFSTR(kIOVideoControlKey_BaseClass), kIOVideoControlBaseClassIDFeature);
    ControlListItem1.AddSInt32(CFSTR(kIOVideoControlKey_Class), kIOVideoFeatureControlClassIDBrightness);
    ControlListItem1.AddSInt32(CFSTR(kIOVideoControlKey_ControlID), 3); //kInputSourceSelectorControlID
    ControlListItem1.AddSInt32(CFSTR(kIOVideoControlKey_Element), kIOVideoControlElementMaster);
    ControlListItem1.AddCString(CFSTR(kIOVideoControlKey_Name), "123");
    ControlListItem1.AddSInt32(CFSTR(kIOVideoControlKey_IsReadOnly), 0);
    ControlListItem1.AddSInt32(CFSTR(kIOVideoControlKey_Scope), kIOVideoControlScopeGlobal);
```

In addition, does anyone know if CoreMediaIO supports hardware snapshot property? It's like telling cmio to grab a still image when the hardware button press is detected.

Thank you for your time.